# Stop touchpad/trackpad 3 finger gestures in windows application

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, gesture, touchpad

Is there a way we can stop laptop touchpad/trackpad 3 finger gestures in WinForms application? Basically, I want to stop/lock user from using touchpad 3 or 4 finger gestures to open new desktop while using a windows application in full screen mode.

1.) Tried to capture windows message while using laptop touchpad but no luck.

2.) From c# code behind tried to update the registry but 3 finger swipe up does show the new desktop and other applications.

Comment: any luck on finding a way?

Comment: Gestures are usually handled by the trackpad driver. System opens new desktop, no matter what the source of the command.

Comment: Would [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/getting-started-with-multi-touch-gestures) source be of any help?

Comment: @cs1349459 that could be useful,  we'll just have to try it to see if you can prevent a 3 finger gesture using it to know. ANy c++ devs who could post a solution using this link?